# Sum of sequence of array

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to create a function that takes an array, gets put into a function that spits out a different array but also sums this up `n` times and multiply by a constant at the end, I think what I'm trying to achieve will be easier to explain in code (until it breaks down):

```
import numpy as np
wl=np.arange(2,10,1)
def change(wl,i): # function that changes the array
    return wl+i #adds i to each element
def test(wl,n):
    c=5
    s=np.zeros_like(wl)
    for i in range(n):
        profile=change(wl,i)
        for idx,w in zip(range(len(wl),wl):
          s[idx]+=c*w*profile 
    return s
```

And at the end my function breaks down `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` My intention for the last 2 lines is this: say i=3, in our second for loop we create an entry that is an array at a given index, when we move to i=4 it adds the new values to the old entries.

Comment: please [edit] and share a example input and the expectedoutput

Comment: ok I will as soon as I can! I'm trying to find a good way of showing it aswell first

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
wl=np.arange(1,5)
def change(wl,i): # function that changes the array
    return wl+i #adds i to each element
def test(wl,n):
    c=5
    s=0.
    p=np.zeros_like(wl)
    for i in range(n):
        profile=change(wl,i)
        s+=profile*b
    for idx,w in zip(range(len(wl)),wl):
        for l in s:
            p[idx]=2*3/(w*4)*l
    return p
```

The solution was to iterate `s` and multiply each element with w, but this is incredibly slow and I hope someone has a better answer that works faster